# Should not bypass certificate error in firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir

I'm using watir-webdriver and ruby. I need to go to the 'Untrusted connection' page in firefox. But watir handles the certificate validation by default. Is there anyway I can change the default settings?

```
 require 'watir-webdriver'
 browser= Watir::Browser.new :firefox
 browser.goto "https://url"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.assume_untrusted_certificate_issuer = true
b = Watir::Browser.new WEB_DRIVER, :profile => profile
```